# Wordpress Media Library error: The uploaded file was only partially uploaded

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to upload files to the wordpress media library to be downloaded by the user however, if a file is over around 10MB I get the error: `The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.` It happens with various different file types. 
I have tried adding `<? php header ("Connection: close"); ?>` in include/file.php, increasing the `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` and `memory_limit` in `php.ini`, `.htaccess` and cPanel as well as `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` in the `wp-config.php` file but nothing has worked. 
The same files upload fine on my local server. 
My last resort would be uploading the files via ftp as the client needs to be able to easily change the files themselves down the track.

Answer (score 0):

Check also

```
max_execusion_time
```

in php.ini, if it's a hosting server, you may ask also directly to the support, sometimes you don't have the privilege to change some parameters (e.g. WPEngine)

---

**EDIT**

From http://richerimage.co.uk/2014/10/wordpress-the-uploaded-file-was-only-partially-uploaded-error-fix/
or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176465/failed-media-upload-the-uploaded-file-was-only-partially-uploaded

> Navigate to wp-admin/includes/file.php
>   Enter the following at the very top of this file:

```
<?php header("Connection: close"); ?>
```

Comment: I tried max_execusion_time, no difference. I can see that the parameters are being changed in wordpress when I update them but I am still getting the error.

Comment: what is exactly the error? Do you have ssh access or can you check apache log error?

Comment: The only error that I get (that I can see) is the wordpress error: The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.

Comment: Did you have a look at this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176465/failed-media-upload-the-uploaded-file-was-only-partially-uploaded